# How to create a scatter plot with color specified for each point individually?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

Using matplotlib I create a scatter plot animation that shows a new point after each second and shows all old points partly transparent. Each point is defined by `x` and `y`, but also by a category `s`. I want the color of the points to be tied to its category. Ideally that means that the array `s` contains values 1, 2 and 3, and the colors belonging to those values are defined seperately. However, I can not get this to work.

What I do get to work is to specify the edgecolors of each point individually in `s`, the code for this is shown below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as plti
import matplotlib.animation

s = [[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]];
x = [525,480,260];
y = [215,180,180];

img = plti.imread('myimage.png')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.imshow(img)
plt.axis('off')

x_vals = []
y_vals = []
intensity = []
iterations = len(x)
colors = []

t_vals = np.linspace(0,iterations-1,iterations,dtype=int)
scatter = ax.scatter(x_vals, y_vals, s=100, c=colors, vmin=0, vmax=1)

def init():
    pass

def update(t):
    global x, y, x_vals, y_vals, intensity
    x_vals.extend([x[t]])
    y_vals.extend([y[t]])
    scatter.set_offsets(np.c_[x_vals,y_vals])
    intensity = np.concatenate((np.array(intensity), np.ones(1)))
    if len(intensity) > 1:
        intensity[-2] = 0.5
    scatter.set_array(intensity)
    colors.extend([s[t]])
    scatter.set_color(colors)

    return ani

ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=t_vals, interval=1000, repeat=False, init_func=init)
plt.show()
```

Simply changing `c=colors` to `facecolor=colors` does not work. Also I have tried to use colormaps but I cannot get it to work using that either.

The resulting animation from the code above looks as below.

[image]

However, the animation should look like this..

[image]

So my question is; does someone know how to tie the facecolor of each point to the category that that point belongs to?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the ultimate goal here. If you want to use a colormap `set_array` sets the color. Without colormap, `set_color` sets the color.

Comment: `set_color` sets the color of the circumference and that works, but I want to set the facecolor and I do not get that to work

Comment: You do not define `colors` in your code; hence it's hard to guess what it should be.

Comment: Ah I accidently removed it, I have included it now.

Comment: I found the problem, it works when I remove `set_array`. Now I only need to figure out how to change the alpha value also.

Comment: alpha is the fourth value in a color tuple, so you can use `[0,0,1, alpha]` instead of `[0,0,1]`.

Comment: Ah of course, it is fixed now the way I want it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurred because the line `scatter.set_array(intensity)` was called before `scatter.set_color(colors)`. So instead of defining the intensity by a seperate variable, it is instead integrated into the colors directly. The following code produces the desired result.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as plti
import matplotlib.animation

s = [1,2,3];
x = [525,480,260];
y = [215,180,180];

img = plti.imread('myimage.png')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.imshow(img)
plt.axis('off')

x_vals = []
y_vals = []
iterations = len(x)
colors = []

t_vals = np.linspace(0,iterations-1,iterations,dtype=int)
scatter = ax.scatter(x_vals, y_vals, s=100, color=colors, vmin=0, vmax=1)

def init():
    pass

def update(t):
    global x, y, x_vals, y_vals
    x_vals.extend([x[t]])
    y_vals.extend([y[t]])
    scatter.set_offsets(np.c_[x_vals,y_vals])

    if t > 0:
        if s[t-1] == 1:
            colors[t-1] = [1,0,0,0.5];
        elif s[t-1] == 2:
            colors[t-1] = [0,1,0,0.5];
        else:
            colors[t-1] = [0,0,1,0.5];

    if s[t] == 1:
        colors.extend([[1,0,0,1]])
    elif s[t] == 2:
        colors.extend([[0,1,0,1]])
    else:
        colors.extend([[0,0,1,1]])
    scatter.set_color(colors);

    return ani

ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=t_vals, init_func=init, interval=1000, repeat=False)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

The normal way to plot plots with points in different colors in matplotlib is to pass a list of colors as a parameter.

E.g.:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot
matplotlib.pyplot.scatter([1,2,3],[4,5,6],color=['red','green','blue'])
```

[image]

But if for some reason you wanted to do it with just one call, you can make a big list of colors, with a list comprehension and a bit of flooring division:

```py
import matplotlib
import numpy as np

X = [1,2,3,4]
Ys = np.array([[4,8,12,16],
      [1,4,9,16],
      [17, 10, 13, 18],
      [9, 10, 18, 11],
      [4, 15, 17, 6],
      [7, 10, 8, 7],
      [9, 0, 10, 11],
      [14, 1, 15, 5],
      [8, 15, 9, 14],
       [20, 7, 1, 5]])
nCols = len(X)  
nRows = Ys.shape[0]

colors = matplotlib.cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, len(Ys)))

cs = [colors[i//len(X)] for i in range(len(Ys)*len(X))] #could be done with numpy's repmat
Xs=X*nRows #use list multiplication for repetition
matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(Xs,Ys.flatten(),color=cs)
```

[image]

Comment: I know how to color them in one go, but the difficulty is in the iterative nature of the problem. I do not see how to apply your solution to my own code. Could you help me with that?